# Shuffle Keywords in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's my keyword ;

> Mercedes Ac Compressor Search Item 2019

I want to shuffle it randomly like i want ac compressor to be first some time 2019 in start some time, like this how can i do it, i know i can do it with array but i don't want it like this can you please suggest or help me ?

Basically i am creating a global search that if a user will search mercedes ac compressor it will get the result and sometime when he/she search for 2019 mercedes it will also display the same result

Comment: I think you want to create strings to _test_ the 'global search' you're creating? May I ask why you don't want to use arrays? It seems the obvious tool for the job.

Comment: basically i have a column in my table that have this value `Mercedes Ac Compressor Search Item 2019` i want to search for it i am not storing array in my table so that's why i am not using array.

Comment: So you want a query that looks for the column that has `LIKE '%mercedes%' AND LIKE '%2019%' `?

Comment: yeah like this basically i am doing LIKE '%Mercedes Ac Compressor Search Item 2019%' but i want it also work like this LIKE '%Ac Compressor 2019%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got a solution, it will work like this.

```
$oldKeyword = 'Mercedes Ac Compressor Search Item 2019';
$keywords = explode(" ", $keyword);
shuffle($keywords);
$newkeystr = implode(" ", $keywords);
```

Now everytime $newkeystr will shuffle my $oldKeyword.

Answer (score 2):

```
function random_words($text = "Mercedes Ac Compressor Search Item 2019") {
  $char = explode(" ",$text);
  $num = count($char) - 1;
  $rand_max = array_rand($char,$num);
  $value = "";
  for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i ++) {
    $i == 0 ? $value .= $char[$rand_max[$i]] : $value .= " ".$char[$rand_max[$i]];
  }
  $new_array = explode(" ",$value);
  foreach($char as $txt) {
      if(!in_array($txt, $new_array)) {
          $value .= " ".$txt;
      }
  }

  return $value;
}

echo random_words();
```

Comment: my solution is short and it's efficient.